# python 3.7.0 + pyinstallerで作ったプログラムを他のPCで開く方法

Tags: python

ネットで書いてあったのを試してみてpyinstallerで.exeファイルにしてみたんですけど他の（pythonが入っていない）PCで開けません。

http://kconcon3.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/01/22/230000

[image: フォルダの中身を見ているスクリーンショットです。フォルダが3つとファイルが2つあります。フォルダ名は順に __pycache__, build, dist です。ファイル名は順に sav, sav.spec です。]

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます。Python が入っていないパソコンだと具体的にはどうなるのでしょうか？　何かエラーメッセージが出ますか？

Comment: コンパイル時のWindowsが64bitで実行時のWindowsが32bitだったりしませんか。

Answer (score 1):

あくまで推測ですが、--onefile を指定してみたらどうですか？
下記の書き込みによると、「引数に「--onefile」と入力しておくと、関連するファイルを１つにまとめることができます。」

https://atelier.hatenadiary.com/entry/2018/07/01/220418

おそらくPythonが入っていない環境で必要なライブラリが足りないのでエラー発生したと思われます。
一回やってみてください。

Comment: 出来ましたありがとうございました。